# How to fit content within the view without scroll in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

[image]

All menu items should be fit within the view,And the scrollbar should be disabled mode.Here the last 2 menus are partialy visible.How to do the same in ionic.

**menu.html**

```
 <ion-content >
   <ion-grid style="padding:0px">
   <ion-row>
     <ion-col style="padding:0px">
      <img src="assets/imgs/HotOffers.png" width="100%" />
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col style="padding:0px">
      <img src="assets/imgs/Massage.png" width="100%" />
    </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
    ...........
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col style="padding:0px">
      <img src="assets/imgs/Profile.png" width="100%" />
     </ion-col>
    <ion-col style="padding:0px">
      <img src="assets/imgs/Settings.png" width="100%" />
    </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: is your menu items are fixed or dynamic ?

Comment: @CodeChanger  dynamic

Comment: Than why you want that grid is not scrollable and its stick with all 8 icons ?